# Results page template of Search API module

Tags: search

In Drupal 8, the default Search uses template file 'search-result.html.twig' to display results.

I have disabled the default search and enable module 'Search API' and Search API SOLR(used for Backend) to perform search in Drupal 8.

I need to customize the search results page of Search API not default search. How can I do this? The search-result.html.twig template doesn't work, with the Search API module.

Answer (score -3):

Search API filters and results are displayed using `views` - so you need to override the views template.

So if you create a view page for your search called "Search API" (`search_api`) - and the machine name of that view is `page` - then you can add the following file to your theme:

```
my_theme/templates/views-view--search-api--page.html.twig
```

You probably want to start by copying in the contents of `core/modules/views/templates/views-view.html.twig` into the above template file and start tweaking it from there.

---

For help creating the actual view you may find these links helpful:

- https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/search-api/getting-started/search-forms-and-results-pages/searching-with-views-0
- https://sweethoneycode.com/custom-search-with-search-api-and-views-drupal-8/

Comment: I am not using views. I am using 'Search API Pages' module to create a search Page. That Module just make a new page of Search. So any idea?

Comment: @Eshban did u find a way to customize search results of 'Search API Pages' module?